# How to convert this json string to dict?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, escaping

After executing the following code:

```
import json
a = '{"excludeTypes":"*.exe;~\\$*.*"}'
json.loads(a)
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
>       obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>   ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

So how can I convert 'a' to dict.
Please note that the string is already in 'a' and I cannot add 'r' in front of it. Ideally, the string should have been `{"excludeTypes":"*.exe;~\\\\$*.*"}`

Also, the following code doesn't work:

```
import json
a = '{"excludeTypes":"*.exe;~\\$*.*"}'
b = repr(a)
json.loads(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

By escaping Escape Character "\":

```
import json
a = '{"excludeTypes":"*.exe;~\\$*.*"}'
a = a.replace("\\","\\\\")
json.loads(a)
```